# Usecase diagram for catalog, category and product management

Tags: uml, use-case, use-case-diagram

So each menu has different categories and each category has products. I'm a bit confused of what usecase I should use.

[image: option 1]

[image: option 3]

[image: option 3]

Answer (score 1):

Use cases are not meant to be used for designing user interfaces and menus. For this purpose, it is better to use more appropriate design practices such as for example [wireframe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Website_wireframe) and storyboards.

Use cases are not either meant to present a workflow or a sequence or event, like first do that, then chose then, then that.  For this activity diagrams are better options.

Use cases should represent actor goals.  The last option seems in this regard acceptable, since a user may be interested to manage each of these items, independently of the user interface and the order it is done.

The second option corresponds to the narrative. But it corresponds to a functional decomposition. Moreover it is misleading,  as it suggest that managing products is dependent on the others, whereas one could well imagine an independent management of products.

The first option would be an alternative if the main goal of the actor is to manage products, and navigation through menus and categories would  just be means to manage the products.  Looking at the context (especially the "reservation" use-case) I understand however, that it's for a restaurant management system, and managing product is only one part of the goals.  This option would therefore be misleading.

Comment: i've also thought of using "Generalization " on "manage products" usecase and then putting 3 usecases ( manage menus, manage categories, manage products). what do you think of that?

Comment: @JosephJoesterJoJo You are doing functional decomposition. That is **not** UC synthesis. Read Bittner/Spence about UCs to get the right idea.

Comment: @JosephJoesterJoJo If menus, categories and products would all be some kind of products, if would be ok. While I understand that a menu could be a composite product. But a category is certainly something else. So you’d need to find a more general generalization.  On the technique itself, this is ok. Generalization is for example used for CRUD operations on a type or CRUD operations by type of operation.   See also:  https://stackoverflow.com/q/72512652/3723423 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/69596025/3723423