# UML: is this use case true for a user authentication?

Tags: authentication, uml, use-case, use-case-diagram

I'm make a use case for a user authentication for a website, and when the user register a new account the website send a verification email to the user.

Is this use case correct? If not, how can I improve it?

This is the use case I made:
[image]

Comment: The new diagram is even worse than the previous one. The bubbles to the right are no UC at all. Further you make the answer below invalid by changing the base of it.

Comment: i didnt mean to delete the image of the question i was trying to make an edit section and i didn't see that the original image has been deleted , its been 1 month since i created my SO account.

Comment: Well, we all have to learn ;-) It's ok now. You can add information to your question and even change parts as long as it's not answered. But after that it's harmful.

Comment: Btw: you are free to open another question if you have (based on the answer). Be sure to check for possible existing answers before doing so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This diagram is syntactically wrong: the dashed lines should be arrows which are either `«includes»` or `«extends»` to explain the dependencies between use cases.

Semantically the diagram could be correct (depending on how you decide for the dependencies) with the following remarks:

- The actor service must be an external autonomous system and not an internal verification service in the same system.
- The use cases shall be independent and have no order between them.  Hence, are you sure it’s ok to first login and then register?
- Breaking a functionality (e.g. registration) down into smaller ones (e.g. send email) is called "functional decomposition".  Although it is not forbidden by UML,  it is not recommended by practitioners, as it leads to overly complex diagrams.

The key issue with this diagram is purpose: despite the many bubbles,  we still don't know what the goals of the actors are, nor what the purpose of the system is. But this is what use cases should tell us.  supposed t.  Use case should focus.  Login and registration are not really goals: they are just a necessary step to do something more meaningful.

Comment: As the OP states it's only about an authorization system. This one has only login and register. A bit thin, but if that's it :-/ ?

Comment: can i add a forgot password use case that extends login use case?

Comment: @unkwn yes, you can and it would be correct semantic.  The question is whether you should, in view of the 3rd bullet. But if your use case isn’t for a complete system, but for  an authentication component, it’s ok.

Comment: @Christophe i edited the question with the full description with the use case i made. can you check if it's correct?

Comment: @unkwn 1) about asking on SO:  please don't edit questions by changing them, because then the answer does not longer match the question and will not be useful for other readers.  If you're tempted to get feedback, leave the original question and add an "edit" section with the new materlial.  But this back and forth  approach should be avoided.

Comment: @unkwn 2) the dependencies seem syntactically ok, and the ones that were previously there are semantically ok as well.  The new ones however like "first name" "password" ... are not use cases at all.  First, it is ambiguous about what's the set of behaviors that is covers.  Second, assuming it's "Enter first name...", it's way too detailed and you should really not go to this level of detail.   See also here:   https://stackoverflow.com/a/75195836/3723423 : use-cases shall not be the description of user interfaces:  user interface is "how?". Use case answers "what/what for?"

Comment: @unkwn 3) Thinks like "phone number, then an opt is sent" is an indication of a sequence.  This is something that you can describe in an activity diagram or a sequence diagram, not a use case.  Things like optional or mandatory information is for the class diagram via multiplicity 0..1. I suggest you rollback your edit to the previous state (because now it's too broad), and that you ask another question specific to the required/mandatory if still needed. ;-)

Answer (score -1):

In short, the diagram is correct, but it is also true that it depends on the level of detail you want to go into with the UML diagram. Generally, in the case of login or registration, we tend to represent more in detail. For example credential check, password recovery and other events.

Comment: No. UC are not meant to show more details. It's just the opposite of that.